# Stokes' Theorem Flux Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, stokes-theorem

Okay, so the question specifies to use *Stokes*' theorem to evaluate the flux integral

$$\iint\limits_{S} \text{curl}( \boldsymbol{F}) \cdot\ \boldsymbol{N}dS
\; \text{where}\; \boldsymbol{F} = \langle \cos z + 4y \rangle i+ \langle \sin z + 4x \rangle j + \langle x^{2}z^{2} \rangle k$$
and $S$ is part of the surface $z = 9-x^{2} -y^{2}$ and $z\geq0$ and $N$ points upward.

I am failing to see a way to solve this problem using a simple method. The correct answer is $0$, but I am not seeing a way that this could be done using any simple method. Is there some type of simplification that I am missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you computed the curl of the vector field and tried using spherical coordinates to evaluate?

Comment: Using Stokes' Theorem, you can collapse the integral to be on the shape of the base of the surface $S$. That is, the desired integral is equal to an integral over $D=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=9\}$, which is the base of the shape $S$. The normal vector to $D$ is only in the $k$ direction, while the curl of $F$ is only in the $i$ and $j$ directions, hence the dot product is zero.

Comment: That should be "less than or equal to" in the definition of $D$. That is, $D=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2\leq 9\}$.

Comment: Why can you collapse the integral to be on the shape of the base? I am not sure that I am understanding this reasoning?

Comment: Because the base has the same boundary as the original shape, and according to stokes' theorem, this means the integrals are equal.

Comment: There is another to solve this, and it's similar to @Dave's suggestion. By Stoke's theorem, $\int_S {\rm curl} \mathbf F . \mathbf N dS = \int_{C} \mathbf F . dl$, where the curve $C$ is the boundary of the surface $S$. Here, the boundary curve $C$ is simply the circle of radius three in the $(x,y)$-plane, $(x,y,z) = (3 \cos t, 3 \sin t, 0)$. It should be fairly easy to see that, at every point on $C$, $\mathbf F$ is orthogonal to the tangent to the curve $C$. Hence the line integral $\int_{C} \mathbf F . dl$ vanishes.